# How to add Schema.org markup to email for a Google Plus review?

Tags: google-plus, markup, schema.org, microdata

Looking at [Google email markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/) - specifically the [Review Action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/actions-overview#review_action). The following dummy example is provided:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
    <div itemprop="action" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ReviewAction">
        <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
            <div itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/FoodEstablishment">
                <meta itemprop="name" content="Joe's Diner"/>
            </div>
            <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
                <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5"/>
                <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="handler" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler">
            <link itemprop="url" href="http://reviews.com/review?id=123"/>
            <div itemprop="requiredProperty" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Property">
                <meta itemprop="name" content="review.reviewRating.ratingValue"/>
            </div>
            <link itemprop="method" href="http://schema.org/HttpRequestMethod/POST"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="description" content="We hope you enjoyed your meal at Joe's Diner. Please rate your experience."/>
</div>
```

Is there someway to customize this to function as a [review for a Google Plus page](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2622999?hl=en)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReviewAction requires you enter a URL that review data gets submitted to. Google+ reviews do not offer such an API so the best you can do is ask users to leave a review and link to the list of reviews.